# How to display data of collection(object collection)

Tags: c#

I have made a collection to store objects of class sendviaemail

```
public List<SendViaEmail> email = new List<SendViaEmail>();
```

The class has a string variable to store emailid. I am adding one object to the list email.

```
email.Add(s);
```

Now the s object is of class type email and it contains an emailed(For eg sad@gmail.com)

When I use foreach loop to iterate through all the values in object and add  all the emailids in listbox but no data is displayed in listbox

```
SendViaEmail s = new SendViaEmail();
for (int i = 0; i < s.email.Count(); i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.email);   
}
```

I tried debugging and in the s object the email = null .
I don't think the code to store email address in the collection works because I m getting null value when I retrieve data.
I m having the email address in string.
How to store string in collection which can hold only objects of class

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should be using a Typed List.

That means the `List` can only contain elements of the `SendViaEmail` object.

```
public List<SendViaEmail> email = new List<SendViaEmail>();
```

You can then add `SendViaEmail` objects to it.

```
SendViaEmail s = new SendViaEmail();
email.add(s);
```

Your loop structure can now take advantage of `foreach`:

```
foreach(SendViaEmail s in email){
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `DisplayMember` property of `listBox1` to `""` and then `"email"`.

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "email";
```

This should refresh the view.

Comment: I tied it doesn't work.But is the code correct .I mean all the emails are stored in the collection

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop rather than a `for`.

```
foreach (string email in s.email)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(email);   
}
```

If you want to use a `for` loop, you need to use the index to get the current item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.email.Count(); i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.email[i]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding *the list* multiple times, instead of adding each of its element.

This is what you are supposed to do :

```
SendViaEmail s = new SendViaEmail();
for (int i = 0; i < s.email.Count(); i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.email[i]);   
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `foreach` as well :

```
SendViaEmail s = new SendViaEmail();
foreach (var item in s.email)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);   
}
```

Comment: @AamirNawab You should provide more context. With what you gave us in the question, there is little to be done.